# Some CSS priority are not same as localhost envrionment and gh-pages

Tags: css, reactjs, github-pages

I have some issue in CSS priority problem in gh-pages.

I tested on localhost environment and code sandbox and it works well. But only in gh-pages, it seems css priority is not applied the same as the local environment.

If I use !important on CSS it works fine, but I heard that use! important is not a good option to use in production deploy. How can I solve this problem?

I don't know why the priority of css changes like this.

[image]

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/sangumee/Crypto-Table/tree/master/)

[Github Pages Link](https://sangumee.github.io/Crypto-Table/)

[Github Code Link](https://github.com/sangumee/Crypto-Table)

Comment: Specificity would definitely be the issue. I assume GitHub Pages adds some additional CSS. You can see if it is overriding yours in the console. The best solution would be to add more specficity to your own selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the order in which the stylesheets are loaded. The last declared style will win.

If that's not the issue you can try adding specificity to your selectors, like instead of `.Post` `div.Post`. This does not scale well tho, because you'll end up having to add specificity for everything conflicting with ghpages and it also could be problematic if you need to override your own styles at some point.